# Create connection with Oracle using New-AzDmsConnInfo

Tags: oracle, azure, powershell, database-migration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tPBJ.jpg)As per article below we can create source connection with Oracle database , however when we put Oracle as a server type in New-AzDmsConnInfo it is giving errors. Could someone please guide me with the Powershell script to create DB connection with Oracle in Azure DMS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/howto-sql-server-to-azure-sql-powershell#create-a-database-connection-info-object-for-the-source-and-target-connections.

Thank you for your comments , please see below details of error :
While creating a new DMS project using below CMDlet it is successful. which is Source : oracle and destination : SQL DB .

New-AzDataMigrationProject -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup `-ServiceName $service.Name`
-ProjectName MyDMSProject `-Location EastUS`
-SourceType **Oracle** `-TargetType SQLDB`

However while creating a new  Source connection info using below command it is getting failed  : it is given in the MS link that Source connection can also be made to Oracle using New-AzDMsConnInfo(link is given )
$sourceConnInfo = New-AzDmsConnInfo -ServerType **Oracle**`-DataSource Oracle`
-AuthType SqlAuthentication `

Error is as below :
PS C:\Windows\system32> $sourceConnInfo = New-AzDmsConnInfo -ServerType Oracle `-DataSource DBNAME`
-AuthType SqlAuthentication `
-TrustServerCertificate:$true
New-AzDataMigrationConnectionInfo : Cannot bind parameter 'ServerType'. Cannot convert value "Oracle" to type
"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataMigration.Models.ServerTypeEnum". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name Oracle to a valid
enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
SQL, MongoDb, SQLMI"
At line:1 char:49

- $sourceConnInfo = New-AzDmsConnInfo -ServerType Oracle `
- ```
                                              ~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzDataMigrationConnectionInfo], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataMigration.Cmdlets.NewConnectionInfoCmdlet

Or please help me with the powershell script which can be used to create Oracle database connection in Azure DMS

-TrustServerCertificate:$true

Comment: Pls add the error to help further

Comment: _"it is giving errors."_   That is totally devoid of diagnostic information.  Software emits error message for the very purpose of assisting in diagnosing a problem. So if you want help with an error, you have to actually _show_ the actual, real, complete error message.  Preferably with some context.

Comment: i have editied my article please help now